# Can I separate a column based on its identity?

Tags: r, strsplit

I'm pretty new to R and I was wondering if it is possible to separate columns based on their identity? For example, I would like to separate column 5 into new columns with all the ones that start with "E-" in one column and all the "D-" in another column.

```
chr1    11046   12418   2   E-H3K27ac,D-Both
chr1    18615   19392   2   D-Both,E-Both
chr1    27209   28559   3   E-H3K4me1,D-Both,E-Both
chr1    35274   35492   1   E-H3K4me1
chr1    36589   38097   2   D-Both,E-Both
chr1    43655   45148   2   D-Both,E-Both
chr1    49265   50054   2   D-Both,E-H3K4me1
chr1    50117   50465   1   E-H3K4me1
```

So that it would look something like:

```
chr1    11046   12418   2   E-H3K27ac        D-Both
chr1    18615   19392   2   E-Both           D-Both
chr1    27209   28559   3   E-H3K4me1,E-Both D-Both
chr1    35274   35492   1   E-H3K4me1
chr1    36589   38097   2   E-Both           D-Both
chr1    43655   45148   2   E-Both           D-Both
chr1    49265   50054   2   E-H3K4me1        D-Both
chr1    50117   50465   1   E-H3K4me1
```

I'm not sure if rows with 3 entries would need to be dealt with first. (In this example I would probably just convert the 2 E- starts in row 3 to just E-Both). Sorry if a similar question has already been asked. I'm still learning the jargon so my search skills about r problems are limited.

Comment: Have a look at `tidyr::separate_rows`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do with this with `base R`.  Split the 'Col' by the delimiter `,` using `strsplit` (if it is `factor` class, wrap it with `as.character(df1$Col)`) into a `list`, then `paste` the elements after grouping by the first character (`substr(x, 1, 1)`), `sort` in decreasing order.  We pad the elements of `list` that have only a single element with NA, `rbind` the `list` elements and create two new columns 'E_col' and 'D_col'

```
lst <- lapply(strsplit(df1$Col, ","), function(x) 
    sort(tapply(x, substr(x, 1, 1), FUN = toString), decreasing=TRUE))
df1[c("E_col", "D_col")] <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
df1
#   chr   ID1   ID2 val                     Col             E_col  D_col
#1 chr1 11046 12418   2        E-H3K27ac,D-Both         E-H3K27ac D-Both
#2 chr1 18615 19392   2           D-Both,E-Both            E-Both D-Both
#3 chr1 27209 28559   3 E-H3K4me1,D-Both,E-Both E-H3K4me1, E-Both D-Both
#4 chr1 35274 35492   1               E-H3K4me1         E-H3K4me1   <NA>
#5 chr1 36589 38097   2           D-Both,E-Both            E-Both D-Both
#6 chr1 43655 45148   2           D-Both,E-Both            E-Both D-Both
#7 chr1 49265 50054   2        D-Both,E-H3K4me1         E-H3K4me1 D-Both
#8 chr1 50117 50465   1               E-H3K4me1         E-H3K4me1   <NA>
```

---

Or another option is to use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` to split the 'Col' and reshape the dataset to 'long' format and then with `dcast` we change it to 'wide'

```
library(splitstackshape)
dcast(cSplit(df1, "Col", ",", "long")[, toString(Col) ,
  .(chr, ID1, ID2, val, grp=factor(substr(Col, 1, 1), levels = c("E", "D")))], 
             ... ~ grp, value.var = "V1")
```

NOTE: As @Frank suggested in the comments, it may be good to keep it in the 'long' format (output of `cSplit(df1, "Col", ",", "long")`) instead of combining it back to 'wide' format

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(chr = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1", "chr1", "chr1"), ID1 = c(11046L, 18615L, 27209L, 35274L, 
36589L, 43655L, 49265L, 50117L), ID2 = c(12418L, 19392L, 28559L, 
35492L, 38097L, 45148L, 50054L, 50465L), val = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), Col = c("E-H3K27ac,D-Both", "D-Both,E-Both", 
"E-H3K4me1,D-Both,E-Both", "E-H3K4me1", "D-Both,E-Both", "D-Both,E-Both", 
"D-Both,E-H3K4me1", "E-H3K4me1")), .Names = c("chr", "ID1", "ID2", 
"val", "Col"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: OP might also want to consider staying with long format (your first step, `cSplit(df1, "Col", ",", "long")`).

Comment: Ah! Thanks everybody! Also thanks akrun for explaining what all the commands/options mean. It was very helpful!